# Why am I getting Incompatible pointer type error as I try to copy one array buffer into another using strncpy?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to copy one `char*` buffer to another `char*` buffer. But as I am trying to do the following using `strncpy` I get an error saying `passing argument 1 of 'strncpy' from incompatible pointer type`

```
struct context {
    char* name[200];
};

void r_msg(context **ctx) {
   char* buffer[200];
   while(1) {
      ssize_t r = recv(socket_fd, buffer,200, 0);
      if(r > 0) {
         strncpy((**ctx.name), buffer, 200);
      }
   }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? How could I copy `buffer` into `name` ? I also tried

```
strcpy((**ctx.name), buffer)
```

but this does not work.

Comment: ...and even then, the code may well not work.   If the protocol is TCP, the usual issues apply: failing to  correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls like recv(), passing char arrays that are not  guaranteed NUL-terminated to library calls that require such arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you show, it makes no sense that you have an array of 200 *pointers* to characters.

As for your problem, for any pointer or array `a`, then `*a` is equal to `a[0]`. Now if you have an array of pointers to `char` (like `ctx.name`)  then `**ctx.name` is equal to `ctx.name[0][0]` which would be a single `char`.

To solve both problems first of all you should change your array to not be arrays of pointer, but arrays of plain `char`:

```
char name[200];
```

and

```
char buffer[200];
```

Then when you copy you pass a pointer to the first element of the `name` array:

```
strncpy(&ctx.name[0], buffer, 200);
```

Or, you let the array *decay* to a that pointer:

```
strncpy(ctx.name, buffer, 200);
```

---

Also note that there's really no need for the temporary `buffer` array or the copying, you could have `recv` write directly into the `ctx.name` array:

```
  ssize_t r = recv(socket_fd, ctx.name, sizeof ctx.name - 1, 0);
  if (r > 0)
      ctx.name[r] = '\0';
```

Note the change in the length argument, and that I added code to make sure that the buffer is terminated as a string (since I don't know if the data received will be terminated).

You should also do some proper error checking (when `r <= 0`) to handle it as well.

Furthermore, if the socket is a TCP socket, then you need to know that TCP is a streaming protocol without message boundaries or packets. A single `send` on the remote side might be split up so you need to `recv` multiple times. *Or* multiple `send` calls could be coalesced and received with one `recv` call. There's no way of telling without some kind of protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: `strcpy` would be simpler than `strncpy` since the buffer sizes are the same. Using  `strncpy` does not defend against anything as it will just omit the null terminator  if the sizes are different (or cause UB if magic 200 is no longer correct).